# How do I set Visual Studio to always build and debug when F5 is pressed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

It used to do this, but now if I don't build the solution first before pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, it uses the last built program.

I must have messed up a setting somewhere I think.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1. Open the *"Tools"* menu, and click *"Options"*.
2. Expand *"Projects and Solutions"*.
3. Click on *"Build and Run"* tab.
4. In the *"On Run, when projects are out of date"* dropdown, select *"Always build"*.

Comment: Thanks man, whatever these issues are, I think stem from my imported settings, I have reverted everything back now and imported only my fonts and colors. It works.

Comment: Remeber to uncheck the "Only build startup project and dependencies on Run"

Answer (score 21):

You are probably working on a multi-project solution:

- Get properties of your solution (right click → *Properties*)
- Click on *"Configuration Properties"*.
- Tick the *"Build"* check box for the project that is not compiled properly.

Comment: How can I make it such that it always Rebuilds instead?

Answer (score 6):

Go menu *Tools* → *Options*. Under *Projects and Solutions* → *Build and Run*.

For *"On Run, when projects are out of date:"*, choose *"Always build"*. Now it should automatically build, and then run (unless there are errors; then the behavior here is dictated by the other setting right underneath it).